# EncodingUtil.base64Decode will throw exception on illegal input

Tags: apex, base64

We have a web service callout in Salesforce to a third party, that renders illegal content, which means that their web service returns a response that claims to be UTF-8 text, but isn't. When I base64 decode that text on my local pc, I can verify that the text is in fact ISO-8859-1 data.

However, EncodingUtil.base64Decode() crashes on this input, so it is impossible to decode it in Apex and then perform some conversion afterwards.

Is there any other way to handle this besides asking the third party to become compliant? It could be done in Heroku, but if possible, I'd like it to be done directly in Apex.

Answer (score 4):

You can take the "long way around" by first converting to hex, then converting to URL-encoded form, and then finally to UTF-8 via ISO-8859-1 decoding.

```
// 'ááááá' in base64 in ISO-8859-1
Blob source = EncodingUtil.base64Decode('4eHh4eE='); 
String hexSource = EncodingUtil.convertToHex(source);
String urlEncoded = hexSource.replaceAll('(.{2})','%$1');
String recoveredText = EncodingUtil.urlDecode(urlEncoded,'iso-8859-1');
System.debug(recoveredText); // 'ááááá'
```

Or as a parameter chain:

```
String recoveredText = EncodingUtil.urlDecode(
    EncodingUtil.convertToHex(source) // source = original Blob
    .replaceAll('(.{2})','%$1'),
    'iso-8859-1'
);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm afraid this doesn't not work in our case, as the source is already corrupt, meaning that they supply an xml response that is ISO-8859-1, but the xml-header says
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
That causes base64Decode to throw an exception

Comment: @EdP The base64 decode in my example is only to get to a point where I have a Blob, which I presumed is where you were at. Your original response data should start out as a Blob, not text. In your HttpResponse, use getBodyAsBlob(), not getBody().

Comment: Yes, I get it, but in our case the response is always a base64-encoded zip file (with corrupted content) within the xml text, so base64Decode is realy the very first thing to do. Thanks for your input though. I'm afraid Heroku might be the only way out, apart from the third party changing their response.

Comment: @EdP A zip file isn't a "corrupted" text file, it's compressed data. You can use [Zippex](https://github.com/pdalcol/Zippex) to decompress the content, and then parse it from there.

Comment: Thanks, actually, we do use Zippex, but it needs to be base64Decoded first and that is the thing that fails when a corrupt xml string is what is inside the base64 encoded string. So again, I'm afraid that Apex cannot help us out here, it seems that Salesforce's base64Decode does more than simply decoding its input, it does some checks as well. Decoding it in Heroku will not suffer from that same issue.

Comment: @EdP That doesn't sound right. Base64Decode results in a Blob, which can hold any data. Unless you mean to say that the base64 string is corrupt, which shouldn't happen if it's base64 compliant (it uses only A-Z, a-z, and 0-9, which are the same bytes in UTF-8 and ISO-8859-1), If the XML is bad, then it's simply a matter of using the above technique on the XML file.

Comment: OMG you're right. When I broke it down into baby steps, it turned out that it really isn't base64Decode() that throws the exception, but rather the .toString() method that was being applied to the unzipped Blob. So then I applied your method and ... presto! It's just like you said.
Side note: I have this unzipString() method built into Zippex, which I'll modify to apply .toString() inside a try/catch and in the catch (assuming it is the ISO-8859-1 causing the exception) I'll insert your snippet and we'll be good to go.
Thanks a bundle.

Comment: @EdP Great! Glad I could help. 